# Why my UITableView can't become longer, and resizing on the screen?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I use XIB to create the user interface of my application, I set the tableView which is 
 `>= 350`, I already set the Constraints, which is at less 350 px, if the UIVIew is higher, it will become longer, but the tableView still stay the same size, if I test it in iPhone 5 simulator, did I set the Constraints wrong? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You have two constraints. Height = 350 and Height >= 350. The only way to satisfy both of them is to set the height to 350.

Comment: But the Height = 350 (purple one) can't be deleted.

Comment: Then don't set the height, set the distance to the top and bottom of the view. Then if the view grows the tableview will grow also. Then you can delete ALL the height constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the tableview to grow with the view it is in then you shouldn't set any height constraints on the table.

Instead set a `Top Edge to SuperView` and a `Bottom Edge to SuperView` constraint.

This way you can delete the height constraints altogether and the tableview will grow with the view it is inside.

**NOTE**

The purple constraint cannot be deleted in your example because it is the only constraint making the layout unambiguous. If you only had an inequality constraint then the view doesn't know what to do...

>= 350 ... does that mean 350, 351 or 17,238,293?

You need at least two equality constraints in each direction to be unambiguous.